# Open external application from Universal Windows app

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp

I need to open an external application (Cisco Jabber Video for Telepresence) when a user selects the "video call" option in my app.

I have found that it is not possible to open the location of the executable in a Universal app...

I have also found that I cannot open an application when it is not associated with any URI schemes...

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Microsoft MVA, some options were presented to us (you just have to fiddle them out):

**Solution 1 (recommended by [this Microsoft MVA tutorial](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618)):**
If you want to start a specific application, you have to create a URI scheme registration, that only the specific application you want to start can handle.
Using the `Launcher`, you can call a specified URI that will only be handled by one application (e.g. `my-cool-uri-scheme://start?param1=123&param2=ABC`).

**Note:** The user will always have the final choice which app to start with a specified URI (that's why this solution is recommended by Microsoft).

*The following solutions will most likely only work in enterprise environments!*

**Solution 2 (*clean* workaround):**
You have to write a proxy Windows application.
This proxy application (almost as in solution #1) registers itself with a specific file extension.
From your UWP app, you then call an imaginary file path containing your parameters (e.g. `C:/Users/CURRENTUSER/AppData/Roaming/YOURAPP/PARAM1/PARAM2/PARAM3/open.my-cool-extension`) - or event the file itself containing the parameters (e.g. XML or RESTful).
The handling application will then use those information to start a specific application (using `Process.Start`) with your given parameters.

**Solution 3 (*dirty* workaround):**
You have to write an observing Windows application.
This application creates a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) listening to a specific folder. So why is this the *dirty* workaround? Because you...

1. Have to create a `FileSystemWatcher` permanently watching a specific drop directory for you UWP app.
2. The user has no control about what will happen (no possibility to override the application to start)

Comment: Solution 1 will do. I thought of solution 2, but I think of it as being dirty. What tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: @vrwim In this [MVA course](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618), it's topic **#15**.

Comment: Sadly, I'll have to go with Option #2 as non-store apps don't seem to have a package name...

Comment: I dont understand the solution #2. When you say "registers itself with a specific file extension", what do you mean? A proxy Windows application could be a console application maybe?

Comment: @Rahnzo Exactly.

Comment: In addition to Herdo's response, the way to registers apps for default URI schemes (That is required in some workarounds he provided) can be found in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx