# How to execute a Console App by passing parameters to it from a Windows Universal App in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, console-application, ipc, uwp

I have a console app written in c# visual studio and a Windows Universal App. The Universal App has data streaming in, I want to pass that data to the console app which plots it. I have tried various way of doing it including the "Process" but my project isn't able to find that library. Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open external application from Universal Windows app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330805/open-external-application-from-universal-windows-app)

Comment: However, it is not an external app, it is in the same project. the example link you posted perhaps is way more complicated than what I am trying to do

Comment: It is an external app. That it is in the same Visual Studio solution makes no difference

Comment: Why do you need a separate app? Why can you not do the plotting in the uwp app?

Comment: I don't need a separate app, but I couldn't find a way to reference MLApp in the universal app, there was no COM server available. If you know of a way to do so, please let me know

Answer (score 4):

UWP Apps are sandboxed, and can't launch external applications.

If the console app is already running, you may be able to communicate with it (by using sockets for instance). But there's no way to launch it (unless it's another UWP app). That's for security reasons, thank to this you can download any app from the store and run them safely on your computer.

Comment: Is there a better way you could recommend to execute what I am trying to do? I am coding in Visual Studio first time and have no idea about all the functionality associated

Comment: @DashD If there was a way to bypass the sandbox, that would defeat the whole point of having a sandbox in first place. If your app needs to interact with a non-universal app, then you shouldn't make an universal app (unless, as I've stated before, that the external app is already running, in which case you can potentially setup some kind of communication channel)