# Directly launch exe in Visual Studio Debug Directory for UWP Applications

Tags: uwp

Visual studio creates an AppX folder when debugging a UWP app. When it's running you can see by right clicking on it in task manager and selection open file location that it's using that entire folder as an app container to launch store app. If VS can do it I know it's possible, so how can you do this programmatically?

EDIT: Ok I probably should've been more clear, I did not mean to literally open the AppX folder in a file explorer. I meant to literally launch the app from that folder as an app container, I'm just trying to get the program to run directly just like VS does in debugging. If I open the EXE directly, I get "This Application can only run in the context of an app container". I know for a fact that AppX is the thing being used as an App Container, but I don't know how VS does it and I need to do it in a seperate classing Windows app that I'm making. Basically I need to run an unpackaged UWP app.

Comment: do what? programmatically open the "Appx" folder in the VS project?

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916696/7331395) answer works then consider "Mark as Answer"

Comment: @VijayNirmal No it doesn't sorry, you should look at the edit I added to my post.

Comment: @NexusDesigns What do you mean by "unpackaged UWP app"? Is it an Appx format file?

Comment: @NexusDesigns Can this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330805/open-external-application-from-universal-windows-app) solve your problem?

Comment: I need this one also.  I have many UWP project files, with an exe in the debug directory, and don't want to open each project to build an appx, install, and run it.  Is there a way to just double click the exe under debug and have it open the application the same way as when invoking debug under visual studio?  I could do it the long way, except I have 40 UWP project folders to go through...

Comment: @Bill Moore I have posted a new answer with the details about how VS does it. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

> If VS can do it I know it's possible, so how can you do this programmatically?

VS can do it means we can use this way to debug our app. It does not mean that we can think about doing this ourself when creating apps. I have no idea why you want to run an unpacaged app.(Maybe you need to be clear about why you want to do it like this) You can consider the following scenario:

1. If you installed this app by debug/remote debug using Visual Studio, you can register an URL to open your app, see URL activation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).
2. If you just want to copy the exe from one place to another place and expect to open it programtically. I don't think UWP technology provide a way for you. It does not meet the security purpose of UWP apps. Please create app package instead. If you don't want to submit to store, sideload is the only way when deploy your app.

Comment: I'll give you a motivation for wanting to directly run the exe in Debug/APPX folder.  I have 30-40 folders of different UWP projects created in Visual Studio, and I don't want to install each and every Appx file just to run them and see what they do.  So I go into the Debug directory and try to run it directly, except it doesn't work.

Comment: Also Visual Studio CMake Open Folder needs to do the same thing (currently it fails because of missing dlls).

Answer (score 2):

To run an application from the VS output (e.g. Debug\APPX) the same way VS does it you need to do two things:

1) register the package via powershell: add-appxpackage -register appxmanifest.xml
2) activate the application via IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/Add-AppxPackage 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx